# Retrieve private key for watch only address

Tags: mycelium-wallet

When sending bitcoin for an ico the mycelium wallet automatically generated a watch only address and sent the btc from there. I need the private key for this watch only address to access my tokens. Is that possible? Thanks, Piers

Answer (score 1):

> **the mycelium wallet automatically generated a watch only address and sent the btc from there**

A watch-only address is one for which you do not have the private-key. It isn't possible to send bitcoin from a watch-only address.

> **I need the private key for this watch only address to access my tokens. Is that possible?**

See [Mycelium](https://wallet.mycelium.com/service.html)

> 'Watch only' accounts
>
> An address stored in the wallet without the corresponding private key, allowing the wallet to watch for outputs but not spend them.

If the address is watch-only, your wallet doesn't have the private key.

[How to manage my account](https://mycelium-support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003784852-How-do-I-manage-my-accounts-) says

> To activate an archived account, press it to select it, and press «Activate» at the top.
>
> To delete an account, press it to select it, open the pop-up menu, and press Delete. Note, you cannot delete your HD accounts, only single address accounts. When deleting an account, you are given the option to delete the account completely, or only delete its private key. **Deleting only the private key will convert the account into a watch-only address, allowing you to monitor the balance and receive payments to the account, but not to spend from it.**

(my emphasis)